# Postgresql: type_modifier in UDT

Tags: postgresql, user-defined-type

In the [manual for creating UDTs in postgresql](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/sql-createtype.html) I found the following statement:

> PostgreSQL allows user-defined types to take one or more simple constants or identifiers as modifiers. However, this information must be capable of being packed into a single non-negative integer value for storage in the system catalogs.

So is there really no way, to store more information that would fit in a non-negative integer? I would like e.g. to be able to store the name of a function that should be called as a default upon insertion on the data (since there might be multiple functions that could work on that data). That is not possible?

Comment: "*a function that should be called as a default upon insertion on the data*" - that's called a trigger. I have no idea what you are talking about. Can you show us an example?

Comment: Sorry for being unclear! Yes, I was thinking of a trigger; but is it possible that the name of the trigger is specified with the data declaration? E.g. assume there are multiple triggers (t1, t2,...), and a udt (my_udt): is it possible that at the time of creation of the table the user specifies ´CREATE TABLE test ( attribute my_udt t1)´ and a function in my_udt interprets that t1 as being the name of a trigger to be added?

Comment: @navititious No. A trigger is coupled to a table (or column(s) of a table, no matter what data type those columns are.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [system catalog for types, `pg_catalog.pg_type`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/catalog-pg-type.html), has the following column:

```
typtypmod integer not null
```

as you can see by running `\d pg_type`.

There is no way to store something you can't fit into an integer because that's how the catalog stores typmods.

The non-negative requirement appears to stem from the use of `-1` as reserved value.

The specific problem you describe sounds better suited to the addition of a column trigger. It sounds like what you really want is [`DOMAIN`s](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createdomain.html) and the ability to add triggers on domains - but unfortunately at this point there is no support for triggers on domains.

Comment: Makes very much sense! Thanks for this very good explanation!

Answer (score 0):

*After quite a lot of research I found a further possibility:*

While it is truly not possible to store more information within `pg_type`, since it is of type integer, there's the option to store information within an attribute of a table.

However, for that purpose you have to change the source code of postgresql: The file `reloptions.c` allows to add in a key-value format `key=value` acceptable fields. Using the SQL `SET` command (e.g. `ALTER TABLE tbl ALTER COLUMN col SET (k1 = v1)`) the key-values can be set. This information is then stored in the `attoptions` field in `pg_attribute` (and not in `pg_type`.